# Social security credits shared between spouses where neither earned 40 credits

Tags: united-states, social-security

A husband and wife, neither of whom earned enough credits, want to combine their credits under one spouse's social security number in order to qualify for social security benefits.  Is this possible?

Comment: Is this related to retirement or disability? How close are they to the minimum number of credits? Have you checked their social security accounts?

Comment: Retirement not disability.  The wife turns 62 next month.  The husband is considerably under the minimum and offered his credits to put the wife over the minimum - she is slightly under.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did a married couple live on if neither of them has worked 10 years in 44 years?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Possibly working cash jobs that didn't pay into the SS system.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to pool or transfer social security credits.

If the wife works long enough to get to 40 credits, both she and her husband will be able to get benefits (the latter as spousal benefits). If the wife is capable of working longer, it would likely be well worth her time.